# Trouble with apache starting on boot with ssl api key

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, centos, varnish

Im Running on Centos,

the trouble is when i restart my server i need to start my apache and varnish service

I use this to start both of them

```
service httpd restart && service varnish restart
```

But i would likw both of them to start when i reboot the server

I read i could use this

```
chkconfig httpd on
```

But this is only for apache could i do this

```
chkconfig varnish on
```

Finally when i do y usual start of httpd , i am asked for my api key for SSL , am i able to incorporate this into resarting both varnish and httpd on start up. Or am i doomed to run this command everytime i resart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean 'ssl private key passphrase', then no, you can't really add the password for a key to initscripts. Instead, you shouldn't store the key in encrypted format if you want to be able to start the service automatically. To convert a keyfile to unencrypted format, you can use openssl:

```
openssl rsa -in foo.key -out foo_unencrypted.key
```